# Linked objects don't highlight in 3.1

Tags: edit-mode

In 3.0, when you entered edit mode, with a linked object, all the linked objects would highlight, but it seems in 3.1, they do not.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fancy seeing you here :) I think it was changed on purpose, since in edit mode the highlight indicates that the user can modify the geometry, whereas you can't directly tweak the geometry of the linked duplicates. Might be worth asking the devs on https://blender.chat

Comment: It still has the same effect, if you edit them you will see the linked meshes update in the viewport. I'm willing to bet this was done because having them all appear in edit mode was less performant, and ultimately unneccessary.

Comment: Hi @Gorgious Good to know that I wasn't missing anything. Thanks!